# Diablo 3 (Xbox360) co-op exp and loot mechanics?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

me and my friends just bought Diablo 3 for the Xbox 360.
We played for a couple of hours in co-op mode (3 players).

One of my friends, who supposedly knew more than the rest of us about the game, told us that in co-op mode all exp and money gained from killing monsters is automatically shared among all party members.

After a few hours of play though, we started doubting that this was not true. 
Money and loot for starters are individual (leading to an annoying grab-fest every time a boss dies).
We still haven't figured out the exp part, and they refuse to quit our grinding for a little bit in order to experiment and find out, so I'm asking you guys to help me clarify:

1) Is exp divided evenly each time an enemy is killed?

2) If not, does the player who dealt the killing blow gain more experience?

3) Is experience gain in any way related to the amount of damage dealt?

4) Do I get exp for every monster killed by the party or only for the one I hit at least once?

5) Do I still get exp while dead (and waiting to be revived)?

6) Do I get experience from special finds (i.e. books, scrolls, etc.) or does it only go to the character who activated the item?

7) Is quest exp shared evenly among party members, or is there a way to get more exp than the others from a quest?

8) Do items that increase exp gain only affect myself or also the other party members?

Thank you for your answers =D

Comment: 6) and 8) is only for the person who owns the item/finds the book. this is based on the PC version though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of this answer is for same-screen co-op.  Online play is different.  I have leveled two characters in coop from 1-8 with simultaneous level ups.  Nothing special was done except that +xp gear was kept equal between them.  I've also observed 3-player co-op with similar results.

> Is exp divided evenly each time an enemy is killed?

Yes. If the players are equal level it's definitely even.  There may be a little catch-up distribution in the case of non-equal levels.

> If not, does the player who dealt the killing blow gain more experience? Is experience gain in any way related to the amount of damage dealt? Do I get exp for every monster killed by the party or only for the one I hit at least once?

No, No, and every monster killed by the party.  Bonus rewards (such as Massacre from a kill chain) and Quests, also shared by the party.

> Do I still get exp while dead (and waiting to be revived)?

I don't know this one - hopefully it doesn't come up much.

> Do I get experience from special finds (i.e. books, scrolls, etc.) or does it only go to the character who activated the item?

Shared by the party.  I have seen two characters level up at the same time when one picks up a book.

> Is quest exp shared evenly among party members, or is there a way to get more exp than the others from a quest?

Shared evenly.  Although it may be level adjusted.

> Do items that increase exp gain only affect myself or also the other party members?

This is it, this is the only thing in the list that is personal.  If you wear more +xp gear than your buddies, you will get more xp.

> Money and loot for starters are individual.

Item loot is individual.  Money is shared by copying.  If one player picks up 10 gold, every player will glow and get 10 gold.

Comment: Your answer matches my experiences for XP. For loot, I've been playing co-op with my wife where both characters are on the same profile, and in that case what we found is that gold is shared between the characters. When we pick up 10 gold, we don't both get it... our shared pool just goes up by 10 gold. If one of us buys a potion for 500, the amount of gold it says we have on our character screens goes down by 500 for both, because it's a shared pool.

Comment: What about 3 characters on 3 different profiles? It seems to me that gold is shared when picked up but not when spent. Could this be?

Comment: I played on xbox360 with different profiles.  Everybody gets a copy of gold pickups.  Every profile has its own purse from which to spend gold, shared across the characters on that profile.

Comment: Sounds like I should have created a second profile so we'd have twice the money!

Comment: So money is copied among profiles, but on the same profile the money is shared among all characters linked to that profile? Seems like a fitting explanation for Sterno's case and mine also...

Comment: @Sterno Honestly, I don't think xbox360 allows one profile on two controllers... so it must be some kind of ps3 madness.

Comment: @DavidB That may be the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I still get exp while dead (and waiting to be revived)?

No, while dead you don't gain experience.

> Money and loot for starters are individual

As **David B** said, money is copied to everyone; it doesn't matter who take it, but money pool is individual, so if you buy things, the rest of the party members will keep the same amount of money.